# Does code run in or on a thread?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, computing

Any programmers around? Which of the following is correct, or more common:

- The code runs **in** a background thread.
- The code runs **on** a background thread.

That's it. Just a simple word different.

As an alternative, the code might also *be executed* in/on a thread, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Either is correct, depending somewhat on the particular audience and computer environment.

Comment: The code runs **as** a background thread.

Comment: @JamesRyan: Not strictly correct. Threads and code are not the same thing. Code can't _be_ a thread.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know if you are joking or trying to be too clever. By definition it is a thread of code, just like a pile of apples. The term does **not** describe any type of container or processor. Code is the only thing that *be*'s a thread. :)

Comment: @JamesRyan: Well, yes, it does. There is more to a thread than the code executing in it. Not as much as a full process, but it's not nothing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there are other objects that describe the thread, but they are not the thread itself

Comment: @JamesRyan: What. The thread is the thread itself. One of the thread's many properties is the code that is executed in it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A thread object in a programming language holds properties about a thread, but it is not the thread itself.

Comment: @JamesRyan: What nonsense is this. I feel like you are nitpicking for the sake of it. "Thread" is well-defined and the code that executes in a thread is clearly only one part of what constitutes a thread. Now you introduce this notion of "thread object" which is a meaningless distinction. I think we're done here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Its not nitpicking I think you just have an incorrect mental model of what a thread is.  And tbh that is vital to which word is appropriate for the OP

Comment: @JamesRyan Pally I am a Senior Software Developer and I know very well what a thread is! I couldn't agree more on the importance of getting this stuff precisely right.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I am writing software for a car and I have a class called car which has all the properties and methods that interact with it, the class is still distinct from the actual physical car. Likewise with threads.

Comment: @JamesRyan: Are you confusing threads with classes that encapsulate the control and management of threads?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, that is what you are doing.  In a CPU a thread is **only** a series of code, absolutely nothing else.

Comment: @JamesRyan: In a CPU a thread _does not exist_! Threads exist only down to the layer of abstraction provided by a scheduling OS, in which they are a lot more than "a series of code". (Modern processors' ability to perform parallelisation across cores and using hyperthreading techniques is entirely orthogonal to any notion of "thread" that you will find in programming).

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you, but if that really matters, I was more thinking of the concept instead of the management class. But I couldn't follow you anyway. At least "in" seems to be more common, according to the votes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*In* a thread (but *on* a server or an OS), in my experience as a programmer.

Comment: I agree.  Compare what you say about *task*, a notion allied to *thread*.  Code can run in a task, but it would be odd to say it runs "on a task".

Comment: In my experience as a programmer, *in* and *on* are used approximately equally w/r/t threads, and *as* is also occasionally used.  Most programmers are not particularly concerned with the grammar of languages designed for inter-human communication.

Comment: But if you were refering to the thread from somewhere else there is a big difference between "wait in a thread" and "wait on a thread"

Comment: @bcrist: I've _never_ heard "on a thread" and it sounds very odd to me. And as for your statement regarding "most programmers" well, blimey, most crappy programmers maybe but not the sort whose particular way of going about life matches the requirements of being _good_ at software development: rigour, precision and care.

Comment: @bcrist:  as a former programmer who is now a technical writer (about 15 years of each) I can attest to the truth of your statement about most programmers' view of humanspeak.  But they are careful and precise in referring to their code.  Thus, it is plausible that "on a thread" and "in a thread" might have completely distinct meanings. So the question was worth asking. Granted, it wasn't really a question of English-language-usage so much as a question of how-do programmers-use-English.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Indeed, but such a distinction would have to be developed between a particular group of programmers.  When the meaning of a noun is changed, the meaning of prepositions used with it may also change.  In this case, it's confounded further by the multiple software engineering meanings of "thread" (thread-of-execution vs. thread object, etc.) English is full of illogical special rules and edge cases; a programmer's memory is better utilized remembering special rules and edge cases that *actually matter*; extra verbosity should be used instead of relying on others' English skills.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Questions of how-do programmers-use-English are as on-topic here as how-do figure-skaters-use-English or how-do English-philologists-use-English (not that there seem to be many around...). The question might do slightly better on StackOverflow, but given the overlap of communities, it's hardly critical. As for most programmers' view of humanspeak you mention, I find this is a kind of legend created and promoted mainly by programmers themselves.

Answer (score 6):

I've heard/read both being used pretty much interchangeably. If you want to make a distinction, maybe look at how the code you're describing is being run.

Example 1:
Given two paths of execution (two threads), and one routine is always run on the secondary thread, one might say that routine is run "on the thread".

Example 2:
Given one primary thread, and a subroutine which starts its own thread to run asynchronously, then it might be said to run "in the thread".

Comment: Yep, been programming over 40 years, and I've seen both tens of thousands of times.  There are contexts where one is probably preferred over the other, but the distinction would hardly ever be critical.

Comment: @HotLicks The context absolutely matters. Tasks run on a thread, but code runs in a thread. The difference comes about because of the different types of abstraction-- in some cases the thread is a platform that hoists up tasks, like the programs that run on a server, while in other cases, the thread is described as a container that holds the code, being that threads are system objects, like processes, but lightweight, and fully contain the code (should it escape, the system would abort execution of the thread).

Answer (score 5):

Use "on the thread" to mean that a thread (usually named) is going to carry out a task. For example, events can be dispatched "on the Event thread." One might also say that "graphics rendering occurs on the UI thread." You wouldn't ordinarily refer to code as running "on the thread," but instead used to describe what task runs in that context. This is roughly analogous to running something "on a server."

Use "in the thread" to mean that a thread (possibly unnamed) is running code. Threads are abstract concepts that operate like a box, and on all modern systems, code runs within that context, and are therefore "in the thread." It's usually described in a general way to conceptualize how threads work.

There is usually only one right way to refer to in/on the thread, and you'd have to use the correct context or it might sound odd to professional or experienced developers.